# Detect packets in a bytestream H264 video feed

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264

We have an SDK that expects packets as shown in the output of

```
ffprobe -show_packets video_file.mp4
```

```
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=N/A
pts_time=N/A
dts=N/A
dts_time=N/A
duration=48000
duration_time=0.040000
size=310484
pos=0
flags=K_
[/PACKET]
...
```

Just wonder if it's possible and if so how involved it is to parse a live feed of H264 byte-stream format into packets in C?  We look at the start codes (0x00 00 00 01 for our stream), but they seem to mark NALUs not packets.  Any pointers are really appreciated.

Comment: "Just wonder if it's possible..." If *what* is possible? Writing output in that format from inside a program? Yes that's possible. Parse a live video stream? Yes it's possible. Something else? It's very likely possible as well. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to elaborate on your problems and your question.

Comment: And just a hint: Don't attempt to parse video yourself, that's almost impossible. Find and use a library to help you.

Comment: The question is: Is it possible to "parse a live feed of H264 byte-stream format info packets in C" into "packets as shown in the output of ffprobe".

Comment: By "how involved it is" we implied "which libraries to use if any or do we have to roll our own".  I thought I was pretty clear, but may be not.

Comment: @ChuBun _"We have an SDK that expects packets"_ do you have a link to the SDK's documentation? What is a "packet" anyways? In H264 there are frames not packets. A frame can be spread over multiple NALUs. If you want to check what you've got, use a **hex editor** to analyse the H264 byte-stream's bytes. You should have bytes starting with SPS, then PPS, then finally a keyframe. See if you can get at least one picture (keyframe) decoded by your SDK.

Comment: It's the PayloadSDK from DJI (https://github.com/dji-sdk/Payload-SDK). 'Packet' is the term from the output of 'ffprobe -show_packets video_file.mp4'.  It's probably the same as a frame.  Basically, the sample app captures results from ffprobe, seeks to the pakets' 'pos' to read a 'size' block of data.  Then sends the blocks to the drone.  My problem is how to get packet's pos and size from a continuous stream?  A frame may contain many NALUS, so I cant rely on the start code.  I guess I could read the source for ffprobe.  Just hope someone already did that and can give me some pointers!

Comment: Have you studied the `ffprobe` source code? It's in C and does exactly what you want... Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Look at the various `libav*` and `libsw*` libraries that are built as part of the `ffmpeg` codebase.  They provide all of the functionality used by `ffmpeg`, ffprobe` etc.

Comment: @G.M.  This was a pilot project and time was running out, so I used a stream with only one frame for my tests.  Will revisit the libraries if project gets picked up in the future.  Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: We ended with a different approach, but I think this task can be done by using a parser (ffmpeg AVCodecParserContext).  Check the decode_video.c source file in the ffmpeg examples for the details.  A video file is used in the example, but I would think it will be the same for a raw data stream.  So the parser will read in buffer of data one at a time and spit out a packet when it can detect one.